# SSIS timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Can anyone provide details on what the three of these mean?

- System::ContainerStartTime
- System::CreationDate
- System::StartTime

The documentation for these three is virtually non-existent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**`ContainerStartTime`** is the timestamp for when a task's immediate parent container (such as a Sequence Container or a For Each Loop) has started executing.

**`CreationDate`** is whenever the package was created.

**`StartTime`** is the time that the package began executing.

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141788.aspx).

Comment: @Eric: Tx. Do you have a URL for this documentation where I can read more?